# What is the reason South Sudan has not yet signed the NPT?

Tags: international, nuclear-weapons

What is the reason South Sudan has not yet signed the NPT? On Wikipedia, it says South Sudan, founded in 2011, has not yet joined. Is there a particular political reason why they didn't join yet? What are the advantages of doing so and what are the disadvantages of signing the NPT?

Comment: It's possible they could not be bothered or are unable to make it happen. It's a very young country that has been in a state of civil war almost from the start. How many diplomatic staff does South Sudan even have? How many treaties has it signed in total?

Comment: It is a good idea to spell out abbreviations